# GWT/RequestFactory/JPA foreign key not merged automatically

Tags: gwt, jpa, eclipselink, requestfactory

I have the 2 following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "brand")
public class Brand {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Brand brand;

    @Column(name = "otherproperty")
    private String otherProperty;
}
```

Basically the brand will be a predefined list that *should* never change, chosen in the GUI from a drop-down list.
However, I'd like to be able to change the brand of my car as any other property.

Here is the method in my DAO:

```
public void updateCar(Car update) throws Exception {

    EntityManager em = entityManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.merge(update);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

The DAO works fine to update `otherProperty`, but if I provide another brand as child of the `Car update` parameter, it won't update the foreign key to the new brand.

I've tried using the `CascadeType` properties, but it wants to update the brand table, which I don't want.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

EDIT: OK I've found a solution, but it looks over complicated to me.

If I add 2 lines in the DAO code in order to explicitly look for the brand to update, it works:

```
public void updateCar(Car update) throws Exception {

    EntityManager em = entityManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Brand lookedUp = findBrandById(update.getBrand().getId());
        update.setBrand(lookedUp);

        em.merge(update);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

However I'm working with GWT/RequestFactory, and have implemented a `Locator` for my `Brand` and one for my `Car`, so I would assume the `Locator` would take care of that business for me.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you find the new brand entity in order to associate it to your car?  Make sure that you have looked it up and changed the reference and not just modified the old brand object's id and name.

Comment: I'm actually using [GWT/RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) so I assume the lookup is done properly by my Locator. Still need to double-check it carefully on Monday!

Comment: Thanks for the hint, indeed my RequestFactory `Locator` doesn't do automatically the look up, so I have to do it manually myself. I'm quite surprised by this behavior, do you think what I did is optimal, or is there something else I'm missing?